# Array and String in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, loops, multidimensional-array

```
a = ['RED', 'BLUE', 'GREEN]

output = R B G

         E L R

         D U E

           E E

             N
```

How to achieve this output ?
(I believe we have to use 2D array methods)

I tried 2 nested for loops for a[i][j], but did'nt get the desired result.

Comment: Please post the relevant code attempts that you have made

Comment: What is the exact output?

Comment: Please see now I have edited the question - one letter from each string on a singlr line is the output

Comment: @AmanJain JavaScript doesn’t have a data structure such as _“one letter from each string on a singlr line”_. What is the exact [literal](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Glossary/Literal) that would produce the output?

Comment: Determine the length of the longest word first, then loop over that length, inside loop over all three input strings - and if there still is a character at that position, output that, else output a space. https://jsfiddle.net/catjrp0v/ - if you need less extra whitespace than what this produces, feel free to refine.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const a = ['RED', 'BLUE', 'GREEN']

// length of the longest string
const max = Math.max(...a.map(s => s.length))

// create 2D array 3 x 1
const output = [...Array(max)].map(() => [])

// for each character
for (let i = 0; i < max; i += 1) {
  // for each string
  for (let j = 0; j < a.length; j += 1) {
    output[i][j] = a[j][i]
  }
}

// pretty print
console.log(output.map(e => e.map(c => c || ' ').join(' ')).join('\n'))
```

Comment: Does this really needs to be answered? If I were you, I could have requested to close this question (Not my downvote).

Comment: Your code outputs `R E D B L U E G R E E N`, what was asked for was `R B G E L R D U E E E N`.

Comment: Sorry I was not able to post my question correctly as it was my first one, now see the output I want, I edited the question.

Comment: @Nitheesh thanks, I didn't see that